# How do I loop 'source ./a.sh' in Bash here?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I'm trying to loop `source ./a.sh` in the code below so that I can try all the possible pincodes for another bash file, how do I do that?

this is my current code:

```
#!/bin/bash

touch output.txt

for pincode in {0000..9999}; do
    echo "$pincode" | source ./a.sh > output.txt
done
```

I'm trying to add a while loop here but I don't know how, I also tried the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash

touch output.txt

for pincode in {0000..9999}; do
    echo "$pincode"
done | source ./a.sh
```

but again, I couldn't get the `source ./a.sh` to loop(im a beginner)

Comment: what's inside `a.sh`?

Comment: its just a shell script that asks for the pincode of 4 digits

Comment: why do you think you need to `source` that script? Try your firoutput.txst code without `ource`. Seems like it should work (either way, actually). Also, I think you should move your output to the "edge" of the loop, i.e. `done > output.txt`.  Good luck.

Comment: hi, added the output.txt after the loop, works now! thanks a lot :)

Comment: Pipelines set up a subshell. `source` is used to run code in the _existing_ shell. So even if you could make `source` generally "work", it wouldn't be doing anything useful -- the very act of setting up a pipeline defeats the point of using `source` (instead of doing a normal out-of-process execution) in the first place. Unless you're using `source` so you can access un-exported variables, but that's silly -- just export them.